# Less don't compile if declare multiple keyframes

Tags: css, less, css-animations, saas

If declare a keyframe in a less file is all ok, but if i declare another keyframe(no tiping errors, I just duplicate working keyframe then change the name) less tell me `unrecognized input`. Instead, with saas have `expected "{", was "@keyframes` error.

the code:

```
@keyframes cloud-animation-1 {
  from { transform:translate(0px,0);}
  to{transform:translate(1000px,0);}
}

@-moz-keyframes cloud-animation-1 {
  from {transform:translate(10px,0);}
  to{transform:translate(1000px,0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud-animation-1 {
  from {-webkit-transform:translate(0px,0);}
  to{-webkit-transform:translate(1000px,0);}
}​


@keyframes 2cloud-animation-2 {
  from {transform:translate(10px,0);}
  to{transform:translate(1000px,0);}
}

@-moz-keyframes cloud-animation-2 {
  from {transform:translate(0px,0);}
  to{transform:translate(1000px,0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud-animation-2 {
  from { -webkit-transform:translate(0px,0);}
  to{ -webkit-transform:translate(1000px,0);}
}​
```

Solutions? Have missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be because of the name mismatch `2cloud-animation-2` and `cloud-animation-2`

Comment: ops... no sorry. Have prefixed with 2 just for debug. Saas showed me `": expected "{", was "@keyframes clo..."`, but all keyframes begin with `clo` then prefixed one with 2. :)

Comment: Btw., what is `saas`?

Comment: Either way I've just tested it with Less 1.7.5 and this seems to be a bug. e.g. `@keyframes 2 {...}` and `@keyframes 2c {...}` are compiled just fine (yes, Less identifier can begin wiith or be a digit) but `@keyframes 2-c {...}` fails (it looks like less mistakenly interpreters it as a math expression).

Comment: A recommendation for your case is to not use such name. It looks like a typo anyway, but what is more important is that the *CSS* identifiers should not begin with a digit (even though many browsers understand such things just fine).

Comment: And w/o this "debugging" 2 the snippet is compiled just fine (though yet again I don't know what is `saas`).

Comment: @seven-phases-max *Sass. :)

Comment: I see. So if you paste above code to http://sassmeister.com/ you'll see Sass compiles it just fine. So it's something wrong with your local compiler (outdated?).

Comment: Ah, and btw. your snippet above has hidden "whitespace" character (but it is not standard whitespace actually) right after `}` of the each third `@keyframes` - this could be a problem too - try to reenter whitespaces/linebreaks manually.

Comment: @seven-phases-max The damn whitespace, now works. Write the comment as answer. Thanks